# Drop down box is empty in edit/create mode in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have this datagrid and in the lines where there a data in there are also data in  the combobox but when I want to add a new line the combobox is empty. Is there any way to get around it so there is data when I  add a new line in the datagrid?

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="po"  ItemsSource="{Binding dækning}" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" 
      Grid.ColumnSpan="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AddingNewItem="Bladdaeking_AddingNewItem"  
       CellEditEnding="Bladdaeking_CellEditEnding">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Post nr">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Postby}"></TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding TblPostNrs}" 
                               DisplayMemberPath="PostNr" ></ComboBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Dækning">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DaekningsGrad1}"></TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                               </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Post by">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Postby}"></TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Oplag">

                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>


                    </DataGrid>
```

This is the object that the DataGrid takes in

```
    public class Bladdaeknik
    {
        private int BladID;
        private int Oplag;
        private int DaekningsGrad;
           private int PostNr;
        private string postby;
       public int DaekningsGrad1 { get => DaekningsGrad; set => DaekningsGrad = value; }
       public int PostNr1 { get => PostNr; set => PostNr = value; }
       public int Oplag1 { get => Oplag; set => Oplag = value; }
       public int BladID1 { get => BladID; set => BladID = value; }
       public string Postby { get => postby; set => postby = value; }
       public List<daos.PostNrModel> TblPostNrs { get;  set; }
     }
```

And the code in the  *.xaml.cs page

```
      private void AddBladDaeknignToDataGrid(int stamBladid)
     {
          var res = BladDækningDao.GetDækningGradByBladId(stamBladid);
           res.Add(new Bladdaeknik() {
           BladID1 = stamBlad.BladID
          });    
           po.DataContext = new { dækning = res };    
          da.DataSource = BladDækningDao.GetDækningGradByBladId(stamBladid);
      }
```

Comment: Where is your `ComboBox` `ItemSource` declared?

Comment: @Aakanksha the combobox itemsource is declared here  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding TblPostNrs}" 
                               DisplayMemberPath="PostNr" ></ComboBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

Comment: So the ComboBox is looking for the ItemSource in your DataGrid properties, which it cannot find. Check your binding errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daekning is a collection of Bladdaeknik.

The datacontext of each row is therefore one of those Bladdaeknik.

When you append, this is also true.  A new instance of one of these Bladdaeknik will be created.

The datacontext of that combo in the new row is your new Bladdaeknik.

If you want some TblPostNrs to show as options then you need to set them up in the constructor of Bladdaeknik for a new instance. For ones you're editing you can go with that or replace them with some others since you can translate your data from database into that viewmodel.

Or bind to a collection elsewhere using a resource or relativesource or some such to provide one list of these for all rows.

Depending on your requirement.

```
 public class Bladdaeknik
 {
     public Bladdaeknik()
     {
         // Fill this.TblPostNrs with data
     }
```

( Apologies if I mis-spelt anything there ).

Comment: This looks more like a comment than answer. Write some code to explaining how to do that

Comment: @Andy like this

Comment: I'd write some code but I'd have to know much more about TblPostNrs. It also seems a bit pointless since the basic problem is that there are no entries in the collection. How these are best added and indeed whether the collection should even be in each Bladdaeknik depends on the requirement.

Comment: @Andy what do you need to know about TblPostnrs ?  There are entities in tblpostnrs in the rows has data in it

Comment: Use whatever logic you apply to create them to create the entries in the constructor of Bladdaeknik